# Typescript fails to compile in different folder

Tags: typescript

I have this extremely weirdo typesctript issue. I'm a so lost on what the problem is, so hope anyone can help me figuring it out.

My problem is only on the REST API, which is a normal express with mongoose, all written in Typescript. Locally all compiles flawless and also on my server - at first..

I'm setting up deployment from pm2, but suddenly the project no longer builds?!? There is 41 errors:
From Arugument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'B' to Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types.

The same errors occurs on our github action. But none of the developers have the issue.

The only difference is the folder.

The typescript and node version are the same:
Typescript: 4.0.2
Node: 12.19.0

Here is the bottom of the errors:

```
src/modules/projects/routes/project-directory.routes.ts:32:60 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

32         ...(req.query.title) ? [projectQueries.match.title(req.query.title)] : [],
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/projects/routes/project-directory.routes.ts:33:68 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

33         ...(req.query.organizer) ? [projectQueries.match.organizer(req.query.organizer)] : [],
                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/projects/routes/project-directory.routes.ts:61:46 - error TS2365: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[]' and 'number'.

61                 return req.query.distance && req.query.distance > 10 ?
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/projects/routes/project-directory.routes.ts:62:21 - error TS2365: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[]'.

62                     distance <= req.query.distance :
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/member/services/subscribtion.routes.ts:24:13 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ project: { news: true; }; workinggroup: { _id: string; news: true; generalDiscussion: true; organization: false; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Subscriptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'project' does not exist in type 'Subscriptions'.

24             project: {
               ~~~~~~~~~~
25                 news: true
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
26             },
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/modules/member/member.model.ts:150:2
    150  subscribtions: Subscriptions;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'subscribtions' which is declared here on type 'MongooseUpdateQuery<Pick<MemberType, "_id" | "isDeleted" | "isApproved" | "oAuthProvider" | "token" | "email" | "phone" | "isActive" | "password" | "passwordVersion" | "firstname" | ... 36 more ... | "privateFields">>'
  node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:3467:5
    3467     findByIdAndUpdate(id: any | number | string, update: UpdateQuery<T>,
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3468       options: QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions,
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3469       callback?: (err: any, res: T | null) => void): DocumentQuery<T | null, T, QueryHelpers> & QueryHelpers;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The last overload is declared here.

src/modules/zoom/zoom.routes.ts:10:11 - error TS2322: Type 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[] | ZoomRole.Participant' is not assignable to type 'ZoomRole'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ZoomRole'.

10     const role: ZoomRole = req.query.role ?? ZoomRole.Participant;
             ~~~~

src/modules/zoom/zoom.routes.ts:12:53 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

12     const signature = ZoomService.generateSignature(meetingNumber, role)
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/plenary/plenary.routes.ts:55:5 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ questions: any; }' is not assignable to type 'PullOperator<Pick<({ questions: string[]; } & "member" & IMember & Document) | ({ questions: string[]; } & "moderator" & IMember & Document), number | "length" | ... 92 more ... | "questions">>'.
      Type '{ questions: any; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<Pick<({ questions: string[]; } & "member" & IMember & Document) | ({ questions: string[]; } & "moderator" & IMember & Document), number | "length" | ... 92 more ... | "questions">, any[]>'.
        Types of property 'valueOf' are incompatible.
          Type '() => Object' is not assignable to type 'never'.

55              $pull: {
                ~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:1423:5
    1423     $pull?: PullOperator<TSchema>;
             ~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property '$pull' which is declared here on type 'MongooseUpdateQuery<Pick<({ questions: string[]; } & "member" & IMember & Document) | ({ questions: string[]; } & "moderator" & IMember & Document), number | "length" | ... 92 more ... | "questions">>'
  node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:3467:5
    3467     findByIdAndUpdate(id: any | number | string, update: UpdateQuery<T>,
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3468       options: QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions,
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3469       callback?: (err: any, res: T | null) => void): DocumentQuery<T | null, T, QueryHelpers> & QueryHelpers;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The last overload is declared here.


Found 41 errors.
```